# add cassandra node fails with ConfigurationException: For input string: "None"

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I have a dse cluster with 4 nodes already. I am adding the fifth node using opscenter.

I installed datastax-agent on this last node which seems to run properly, then using the opscenter, I proceeded to add the node. It first reports that it is loading new software onto the node, then errors out.

in /var/log/cassandra/system.out I see this error

ERROR [main] 2015-03-18 15:04:27,080 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 117) Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: For input string: "None"
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$1.validate(Murmur3Partitioner.java:178)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:447)

I can't find out where this configuration comes from and how to fix it.

Can someone help?

Comment: What version of DSE are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the Murmur partitioner did not like the token value from your configuration. Exception is thrown out of [Murmur3Partitioner.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/2.0.12/org/apache/cassandra/dht/Murmur3Partitioner.java?av=f)

```
170       public void validate(String token) throws ConfigurationException
171        {
172            try
173            {
174                Long i = Long.valueOf(token);
175            }
176            catch (NumberFormatException e)
177            {
178                throw new ConfigurationException(e.getMessage());
179            }
180        }
```

Check what that value is in your cassandra.yaml. I suspect you should see "None" in place for the token value.

Comment: you are completely right. opscenter put a None there, where as all the other nodes has blank for value. After remove None, the node attempts to start but this time it fails with IllegalStateException: unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range (548346432033587391,579739426412622299]

Comment: This is an unrelated problem. The error means that you have a node in the cluster that is the only source for some token ranges, which is either dead or down. For example if you have replication factor set to 1 for some keyspaces, and one of the nodes is down, the cluster can't stream any data for these ranges into the new node since the only source is unavailable. You should either decommission that node completely, or start it again.

Comment: Thanks, there was indeed another node which was down when I tried bringing up the new node. After bringing up that node first, I am able to move to the next step, which is however, still stuck. On the opscenter  console, I went through the sequence for adding a new node, and ends up with "Error provisioning cluster: Request ID is invalid"

Comment: ok, pls ignore last post. I was able to bring up the new node.